# How to make global navigation show drop down menu?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, variations, sub-site

Guys here's my situation.

I have a site in English and Arabic (using Variations) as below.

English (main site)
Arabic (target)

I want to create a sub site called "About" with following pages. So basically anyone clicking on "About" will see these links in left navigation.

About Us
Services
Contact Us

Now here's my problem. When I create this site in Variation Root then the SharePoint shows "About" as separate heading on top (global navigation) with these link in drop down menu which is fine. But problem is all these pages go to variation root and not English or Arabic sites. You see I want "About" to come under both English and Arabic sites so clicking on "About" under English will open English About site and clicking on "About" under Arabic will open Arabic About site.

So If I create "About" site under English instead of Variation Root then although site is created, it doesn't show "About" as separate heading in top (global navigation) with links in drop down and instead the "About" is shown as drop down under "English".

So basically I want "About" to appear as separate heading with its links in drop down BUT clicking on these links or About should take user to respective English or Arabic site instead of Variation Root site.

How do I do that?

**EDIT**
Please see following screenshot as it explains it better.

[image]

The above is how it is currently appearing. To achieve this I simply did the following:

1. Created a subsite named "About" under "English" which is main site
2. After some time SharePoint created a copy of "About" under "Arabic"

But I don't want to show menu like this. I want to show it like following:

[image]

To achieve above case I did the following:

1. Create a new subsite "About" in Variation Root (and not under "English")
2. Now it appears as separate menu BUT since it is not created under English hence its Arabic version is not created by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by choosing "Show current navigation...." (the last one) option in Navigation settings for current site instead of "Show parent navigation..."

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it properly ;)

have you done this?

your "about us" is in the global navigiation as the default language!

the pages that you need as the language variation would be done like so:

as i noted above as your about is in global its using the global language what is english! you need it as a subsite, once you have created a subsite you can then do the following as below:

[image]

[image]

as you can see you have the main site whats in english and then you create another sub site in arabic that is inline with the english subsite! then in "site content and structure" navigate to "site variation" and link the arabic site to it :) as shown in the images!

sooo you have:

```
root site (default language) -
            ->about us (english subsite)
            ->about us (arabic subsite)
```

anything created in the root will be in the root language that you installed with! its the subsites that you need to change ;), just make sure that you set them up correctly!

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/24/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-9-creating-site-variants.aspx

Comment: I am already done it like this. Please check my question above as I have edited and added more information with screenshots.