# Problem with translate menu in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, editing-menu, menu

I have problem with translate menu in Sharepoint Online.

I create i.e. xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet with MENU (About us, People, Software, Hardware) and I want translate this MENU to english. If I translate MENU to english (i.e. "O nas" > "About", my default language (polish) is changed too. I don't want like that. I want choose english or polish MENU. I have similar problem like:

[How to make global navigation show drop down menu?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75025/how-to-make-global-navigation-show-drop-down-menu)

[image]

But I have Sharepoint Online. I have in "Page content" my all pages (About us, People, Software, Hardware) and one folder "en" with similar pages (MENU).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Language settings has changed in SharePoint Online. For now, we have personal preference language and regional settings in delve. The site navigation will get translated based on these personal settings. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7) is a walkthrough about the steps.

And if you like multilingual communication sites, pages, and news : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c

Still, if you want similar experience like you have set before, for team site you can edit the left navigation to hold sub links under the English and Arabic option.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that the base language of the site is Polish and that English is one of the alternate languages.

In order to change the text of the navigation for people whose language is English, you first have to change your language to English.  As you mentioned, you have two different accounts, one set to Polish the other to English, so use the English one. Confirm that the UI is is English by seeing that terms like "Share", "Edit", and "Search this site" are in English now, not Polish.

Click on "edit" next to the navigation menu, then on the "..." and "Edit" next to the menu item to be translated. Replace the original Polish Display name "O nas" with English Display name "About".  Do not change the URL, that is not language-specific. Repeat for all menu items, then press the Save button.  If the editing prompts, for example the "Save" button were in English and the site language was not, then the text that you changed will only affect the English version.